# converting unixtime to mysql datetime retaining fractions of a second

Tags: php, datetime, mariadb

```
$id["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]="'".date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s.', $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]).substr((($_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]-floor($_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]))),2,20)."'";
```

Say $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] =157888888888888.98765

```
$t=new DateTime()
$t->setTimestamp( only accept an integer)  Fail
```

Also the **date** command just cuts it off, even if you add **u** to the format it just adds 00000 and not the real number of milliseconds.

Most functions I can find just cut off the .98765 and I don't want that.

I put together a hack shown above.  Is there a better way and/or more cpu efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] );`

The docs say that `date()` will trim the milliseconds because it expects an integer, but this function won't.

Comment: Ok, but this incomplete.  It needs a second command to convert back to a string.
$t =new DateTime();
$t->createFromFormat("U.u", $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] );
$id["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]="'".$t->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u')."'";